# Como formatear un campo time en Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Quisiera saber si existe una forma de darle formato de 12 horas a un campo time en postgresql, ya que, almacena las horas de esta forma 13:30:00. Quisiera que al enviarle una hora como esta: 03:24 PM se guarde tal cual.

Mi tabla, llamada **tbledc_hora** tiene los siguientes campos:

**id_hora** (primary key)

**nu_hora** (integer)

**ho_inicio** (time without time zone)

**ho_fin** (time without time zone)

**in_status** (integer)

**id_usuario_registra** (integer, foreign key)

**fe_registro** (timestamp without time zone)

**id_usuario_actualiza** (integer, foreign key)

**fe_actualiza** (timestamp without time zone)

**id_nivel_academico** (integer, foreign key)

Donde **ho_inicio** y **ho_fin** son los campos a los que quiero aplicar el formato.

La version de Postgresql que utilzo es la 13.1

Comment: Estas preguntas siempre deberían contener la definición de la tabla y la versión de la BD que se está usando.

Answer (score 0):

Según [la documentación oficial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/datatype-datetime.html), el formato del campo tipo time (con o sin time zone) es:

| Name | Storage Size | Description | Low Value | High Value | Resolution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| time [ (p) ] [ without time zone ] | 8 bytes | time of day (no date) | 00:00:00 | 24:00:00 | 1 microsecond / 14 digits |
| time [ (p) ] with time zone | 12 bytes | times of day only, with time zone | 00:00:00+1559 | 24:00:00-1559 | 1 microsecond / 14 digits |

Incluso [si le entregas una hora en formato 12H](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TIME-TABLE) (03:45:00 PM), igual la va a guardar en el formato del campo que te indica.

La cosa es que hagas la consulta asignando el formato de salida deseado. Algo como

```
select 
to_char( to_timestamp ( '15:24:00', 'HH24:MI:SS' ) , 'HH12:MI:SS PM' );
```

Que, aplicado a un campo de una tabla teórica que no nos has mostrado, sería algo como

```
select 
to_char( <campo_tabla_mágica>, 'HH12:MI:SS PM' )
from tabla_mágica;
```

Y aplicado a tu tabla, sería algo como

```
select 
to_char( ho_inicio, 'HH12:MI:SS PM' )
from tbledc_hora;
```

Comment: Entiendo, hay alguna forma de que hacer que cada vez que se haga una consulta SELECT devuelva estos campos ya formateados, es decir, hago una consulta que me devuelva todos los registros de la tabla y que pueda ver estos con el formato 12?

Comment: ¿Ya probaste la segunda consulta que te propuse? Ni siquiera has editado tu pregunta para saber cómo es tu tabla...

Comment: Ejecute la segunda consulta, y en efecto me regresa el campo formateado. Pero quisiera saber si es posible que al ejecutar un simple SELECT este traiga los campos formateados por defecto. Ejemplo: select from tbledc_hora where id = 2

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo es un simple select. Tal vez estás habituado a preprocesar los datos en otra capa, en presentación o algo así. Pero esto es normal al interactuar con la BD. Y, como te dije, el formato en el que se almacenan los datos de campos TIME es uno solo, así que debemos inetarctuar con él de acuerdo a lo que necesitemos